# Django REST Framework. How to get full url of a page with protocol, domain, and path?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There is **Django REST framework**. I need to unload the full path of the page into the  tag.
For example, there is a page:

```
https://domain-name.com/category/article
```

In **serializers.py**:

```
class someClass(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.URLField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = onlyURL
        fields = ['url']
```

This does not work correctly, since I do not get the full url, only part:

```
<url>**/category/article**</url>
```

How to get full url with protocol, domain, and path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`serializers.SerializerMethodField()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for this. For example:

```
class SomeClass(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = OnlyURL # using CamelCase for declaring Model Class
        fields = ['url']

    def get_url(obj):
       request = self.context.get('request')
       abs_url = obj.get_absolute_url()
       return request.build_absolute_uri(abs_url)
```

Also make sure to pass `request` as [extra argument](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) or use Generic Views/Viewsets for this implementation.

Comment: Hello! Yes, this is exactly what I need. Thank you!